# Does AMPscript have nested if options?

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript

Can I join multiple if's like this?

```
IF NOT EMPTY (@customernumber) THEN

    SET
    SET

    IF @usmsopt == "False" AND @presmsopt =="True" THEN

       SET

    ELSEIF

       SET

    ELSEIF

       SET

    ELSE

        SET

    ENDIF

ENDIF
```

Is it acceptable?

Does it goes like satisfy condition first and then set things and if satisfy the second condition then goes below set and so on.

Comment: Did this answer your question?  If so, would you mind checking it as answered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, this is exactly how it works.